# How to detect request referrer in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, referrer

We have an asp.net website. When a user visiting the site, we want to check the referrer and if the referrer is some malicious site, we want to block the request. The code we are using is

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() == "MaliciousSite.com"){
    /*do  action*/
}
```

But with below script request, referrer always is null and we cannot find the source of request.

```
data:text/html,<script>location='http://www.oursite.com/'</script>
```

is there any way to find the referrer if the person is redirected by this script?

Comment: If your site always has a referrer, then block anything without? referrer as I recall is easily spoofed as well as not given

Comment: referrer is not important ,we want to detect the source of request that made of mentioned script

Comment: How else are you expecting to tell where it came from?

Comment: You're better off checking REMOTE_IP. That's not always accurate as a proxy, VPN, etc. can mask the true IP, but for the purposes of blocking known malicious users, it would probably work fine. However, this whole thing is better handled at the IIS level. No need to involve ASP.NET at all; you can blacklist IPs directly in IIS.

Comment: `Request.UrlReferrer` will be `null` unless the user has clicked on a link that calls your server method (for example, if you type the url in the address bar, `UrlReferrer` not sent in the request and its `null`)

Comment: So how we can distinguish between user that redirect to our site with typing address in address bar and user that redirect with execute mentioned script?